# Debian 9 detects the monitor on the HDMI port but the monitor display nothing

Tags: debian, multi-monitor, hdmi

My laptop runs on Debian 9 and I try to have a dual monitor.

My first monitor use the VGA ports and works well but the second use the HDMI port and displays nothing.

However, the monitor is detected by my debian like you can see below:

[image]

You can see what is my processor Graphics Controller below:

```
lspci | grep VGA
00:02.0 VGA compatible controller: Intel Corporation 3rd Gen Core processor Graphics Controller (rev 09)
```

You can see below the output of the command `xrandr -q`:

```
HDMI-1 connected 1920x1080+1920+0 (normal left inverted right x axis y axis) 531mm x 299mm
   1920x1080     60.00*+  59.94  
   1600x1200     60.00  
   1680x1050     59.88  
   1280x1024     75.02    60.02  
   1440x900      59.90  
   1280x960      60.00  
   1152x864      75.00  
   1280x720      60.00    59.94  
   1024x768      75.03    70.07    60.00  
   832x624       74.55  
   800x600       72.19    75.00    60.32    56.25  
   720x480       60.00    59.94  
   640x480       75.00    72.81    66.67    60.00    59.94  
   720x400       70.08  
DP-1 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
```

Comment: It is not clear to me what is the question. What shows on your secondary monitor (Ancor 24")? It seems to be detected correctly. By "nothing"  you mean it is just black?

Comment: Yes, it is just black.

Comment: does your desktop get extended? (can you move the cursor into and around the black monitor part?)

Comment: Yes, my desktop get extended.

Comment: does your setup ever shows anything on that monitor? For example, if you set it up as the ONLY primary monitor, does it show the desktop? What about other live distros, etc?

Answer (score 0):

It is not possible to diagnose this problem without more details. If your monitor gets detected with the correct name (Ancor Communications is likely an ASUS monitor) and your desktop gets extended correctly but it is still black, it could very well be a problem with the monitor itself or the connection. Here are some things you should try:

- Check that this monitor works properly by plugging it somewhere else via that same port, use the same HDMI cable and adapters.
- Make sure your monitor is on and has the correct "source" selected and it is not in manual mode, stuck in some other input.
- Perform a factory reset on the monitor using its OSD, if possible.
- Make sure the HDMI cable and/or adapters you are using are not defective.
- Use a different live Linux distro on a USB stick to see if the problem persists.
- Try using the "mirrored" setting and different (lower) resolutions, to see if you ever get an image.